# Ошибка в sqlite, flask, python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

**Лог ошибок:**

```
D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Всё/Кирилла/Проекты-PYTHON/PyCharm/MySite/app.py
Сервер запущен
ERROR:app:Exception on /register [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 681, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:/Всё/Кирилла/Проекты-PYTHON/PyCharm/MySite/app.py", line 171, in register
    db.session.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1406, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 820, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 799, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3224, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3364, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 198, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3324, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 453, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 627, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 242, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1219, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1520, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 313, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1389, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 198, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "D:\Всё\Кирилла\Проекты-PYTHON\PyCharm\MySite\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 681, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (login, password) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('123', '123')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

**Мой код:**

```
from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, login_required, logout_user, UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash

from waitress import serve


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'SERNFoisfdbhBWFgh2456y'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///itPanda.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = LoginManager(app)

print("Сервер запущен")

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True )
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id


class User (db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True )
    login = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


@app.route("/help")
def help_page():
    return render_template("help.html")


@app.route("/create-article", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def create_article():
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form["title"]
        intro = request.form["intro"]
        text = request.form["text"]

        article = Article(title=title, intro=intro, text=text)

        try:
            db.session.add(article)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/posts')
        except:
            return "При добавлении статьи произошла ошибка"
    else:
        return render_template("create-article.html")


@app.route("/posts", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def posts():
    articles = Article.query.order_by(Article.date.desc()).all()
    return render_template("posts.html", articles=articles)


@app.route("/posts/<int:id>", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def post_detail(id):
    article = Article.query.get(id)
    return render_template("post-detail.html", article=article)


@app.route("/posts/0")
@login_required
def redirect_to_posts():
    return redirect("/posts")


@app.route("/posts/<int:id>/delete")
@login_required
def post_delete(id):
    article = Article.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(article)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("/posts")
    except:
        return "При удалении статьи произошла ошибка =("


@app.route("/posts/<int:id>/update", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def update_article(id):
    article = Article.query.get(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        article.title = request.form["title"]
        article.intro = request.form["intro"]
        article.text = request.form["text"]

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/posts')
        except:
            return "При редактировании статьи произошла ошибка"
    else:
        return render_template("post-update.html", article=article)


@app.route("/login", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login_page():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    if login and password:
        user = User.query.filter_by(login=login).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)

            next_page = request.args.get('next')

            return redirect(next_page)
        else:
            flash('Логин или пароль некорректные!')


    else:
        flash('Пожалуйста, заполните поля логина и пароля!')

    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route("/logout", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))



@app.route("/register", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    password2 = request.form.get('password2')

    if request.method == "POST":
        if not (login or password or password2):
            flash("Пожалуйста, заполните все поля!")
        elif password != password2:
            flash("Пароли не совпадают!")
        else:
            new_user = User(login=login, password=password)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('login_page'))

    return render_template("register.html")


@manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)


@app.after_request
def redirect_to_signing(response):
    if response.status_code == 401:
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))

    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

Как мне избежать ошибки:

```
new_user = User(login=login, password=password)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user
```

В вашей базе нет таблицы `user`. Добавьте её или сделайте подключение к другой базе, где есть такая таблица.

Comment: Правильно, понятно и главное без воды.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить?